# Is it good to use UNIQUE index?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a register of students, the main table is this one and I just wanna make sure there won't be students with duplicated names, emails, etc. ID is the main key so I don't need to use a PK.

```
CREATE TABLE student(
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
campus_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
first_career_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
second_career_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NULL,
name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
password CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
phone TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL,
UNIQUE(id),
UNIQUE(name),
UNIQUE(email),
UNIQUE(phone),
FOREIGN KEY(first_career_id)
    REFERENCES career(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(second_career_id)
    REFERENCES career(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I could validate those fields when inserting them through the applicacion, which way is better?

Comment: students can have the same name ! emails cannot.

Comment: Since I won't use a WHERE clause with name, email, phone I think I will definitly remove the UNIQUE index and validate via application

Comment: It cannot be the same name because the enter the full name

Comment: YES, students can have the same full  name! Any system that would disallow that is garbage! They could have the same phone; landline of 2 students living in same house.....

Comment: Ok I will re think this design, it's good that it's not the final model yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If uniqueness is a domain constraint (which it is in your example), then create a UNIQUE constraint on the columns(s) (which creates a unique index for you).

```
ALTER TABLE student 
ADD CONSTRAINT ux_student_email
UNIQUE (email)
```

If you can be 100% sure (and future proof) that no other application will insert data, then ensuring uniqueness in the application is fine. If you value correctness, add a constraint at the database level in addition to checking in the application.

Comment: Sure, I don't store passwords as plain text but the hashed text which is 60 characters long that's why I use CHAR(60)